# Change the text and background colour of the header column in Bokeh DataTable

Tags: html, python-3.x, bokeh

I am using a standalone bokeh html document and it has various tabs, in one of the tabs is a DataTable.

I recently changed the background colour of the HTML to black and lost the text in the header columns, I would now like to change the colour of the text and or background colour to make them visible again.

I am using HTMLTemplateFormatter to colour individual columns no problem but cannot find a way to format the header, can anyone help me here?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right now today, there is not a way to do this in Bokeh. (See Discourse topic: https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/colored-fields-name-of-datatable/6879/2)  Looks like there's not a GH issue for it yet either, so you might want to submit one.